# How do I get HTTP VERB from Python Requests 'Response' objects?

Tags: python, wrapper, python-requests, urllib3

From looking at their source it appears that the `method` member attribute is what I want.

https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/master/requests/models.py

To summarise by example, this is what I want:

```
>>> r = requests.get("http://httpbin.org/get")
>>> print r.method
'GET'
```

However I can't figure out if there's a way to get it (without writing my own hacky wrapper)...

Comment: No, the original request verb is not stored on the response. Why not store that *when you make the request*?

Comment: You mean call `my_fun(func=requests.get, verb='GET', url)` and then within that `def my_fun(func, verb, url):` have `print verb; return func(url)`?

Comment: Or `func.__name__.upper()` perhaps (not use `verb` at all), but yes.

Comment: Ahh, always forget about the introspection in Python (I'm an old-school C++ buff); thanks for the tip :)

Comment: But, with the `request` attribute (which I conveniently forgot about), Jon's answer is much more convenient for you. Just use that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's stored in the `request` attribute of the response:

```
>>> r = requests.head('http://www.example.com')
>>> r.request.method
'HEAD'

>>> r = requests.get('http://www.example.com')
>>> r.request.method
'GET'
```

Comment: Perfect, precisely what I was looking for :D